# Setting webview background image to a resource graphic in Android

Tags: android-webview, android, android-resources

I'm trying to set the background of a webview to a drawable image resource in Android.

From the sdk it seems something like this would work but it doesn't.

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

web.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundmain);
web.loadData(profile, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Any idea's?

Answer (score 66):

As always you tend to figure these things out as soon as you ask the question. For the benefit of others, the layout that I'm using, LinearLayout, can take a background parameter that can be a colour or a resource.

So in my views .xml file I simply added a

```
android:background="@+drawable/backgroundmain"
```

and use

```
web.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

To make the webview transparent to see the background image behind.

Answer (score 27):

It will work perfectly, if you do something like this:

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```

Answer (score 3):

If not working on Android 3.1, try fix the **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```