# Android: Transparent WebView over Camera Preview

Tags: android, camera, webview

Just a general question and maybe someone has an idea: Is it possible to have a transparent WebView over a Camera SurfaceView and use HTML/CSS for creating the overlay?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- in XML -->
        <WebView android:id="@+id/webkit"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxWidth="200dip"
            android:maxHeight="200dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

            // onCreate
            barcodeBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
            ...  // somewhere in runtime 
            barcodeBrowser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String downloadLink = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260422/setting-webview-background-image-to-a-resource-graphic-in-android";


            barcodeBrowser.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0,0,0,0));

            barcodeBrowser.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
            barcodeBrowser.loadUrl(downloadLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, setting transparent background for the `WebView` and overlaying it atop `SurfaceView` using `FrameLayout` ?

Comment: Tried that - doesn't work really. I don't get the WebView transparent. Tried everything from setBackground(0) to CSS transparent statements. The WebView stays white.

Answer (score 0):

Add the surfaceview and the webview to a framelayout, then mWebview.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000) works for me