# Is it possible to use drawables (not images) in WebView?

Tags: android, html, webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@Android display /res/viewable in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630829/android-display-res-viewable-in-webview)

Is it possible to use drawables (shape, gradient, etc.) in WebView (inside `img` tag)?

P.S. I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792604/html-imagegetter). So, I know how to insert image, but what about other drawables?

**EDIT**

For example: I need to display circle in WebView (without using canvas).

Comment: @TryTryAgain, as I said (twice) I don't need an image. However, thanks.

Comment: sorry I thought that would be interchangable with XML drawables, would this be more suitable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260422/setting-webview-background-image-to-a-resource-graphic-in-android ?

Comment: I guess I'm not exactly sure of the specific use you are looking for, in the question's current state, but would using an external layout be an option? http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Comment: Comment on closing this question: answers to previous question may no longer be valid. See answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105913/android-4-0-webview-loadurl-oddity for why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert Base64-encoded image data directly in the URL for the <IMG...> tag. The URL format is “data:*mimetype*;base64,*data*”. For example see [here](https://github.com/ldo/ti5x_android/blob/master/mlsrc/help11.html).

Comment: Looks like it will work ) At least now I can compress Drawable into Bitmap, get byte array from Bitmap and then encode array as Base64.